# Image resizing, maintaing image size - beginner question

Tags: images, image-quality

I am attempting to resize an image from 480x800 to 320x240. Below are the results. The original image has an oval shaped circle whereas the re-sized image has a more spherical shape. Is it possible to re-size the original image so that the circle and rectangle are in their original proportions but smaller?

Is there (hopefully free) software that can achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it even in Paint:

```
1. Open your 480x800 image file in Paint
2. Ctrl + W
3. Resize and Skew window will pop up. Resize by Pixels
4. Verify that checkbox with Maintain aspect ratio is checked.
5. Write into vertical window 240 and click OK.
6. Your image will be resized to 144x240
7. Copy this image and create new file
8. Ctrl+W. Resize using pixel resizing while maingint aspect ration is unchecked.
9. Horisontal 320 and Vertical 240. Click OK
10.Paste image from clipboad and drag it to the center.
11.Congratulations ! :)
```

[Here](http://www.aram.ee/resize) is the result

Comment: Thanks, what if the original image has a background, I dont think above method will still work without losing image quality?

Comment: this is how you maintain the shape. the keyword here is "aspect" or aspect ratio. It is the ONLY way to resize without changing the shape of the box. Regarding backgrounds, you will need to decide to: 1) CROP the image so the shape is the same, or 2) FILL in the extra background areas manually.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're doing, it's not working. You're not resizing proportionately.

see this if you can do  with the help of gimp

[cool solution for image resizing](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11503.html)

Comment: "wherever i know your doing something wrong its not working from all corner." I dont understand ?

Comment: I believe English is not Jack's first language. I will try to edit so it makes more sense to a native speaker.

Comment: Jack, did I rewrite you incorrectly? If I misunderstood you, please rewrite your comment so it reflects what you intended. I did not edit your comment to belittle you, and I think it's great that you are so active in a foreign language. That particular sentence *was* really hard to understand, though.

Comment: no i agree, English is not at all my first language, I'll take care of this...to reduce ambiguity in my answers... your comment lead me to something, hope i'll improve my self as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a free online one too. Like PhotoShop. 
Check here:
http://pixlr.com/editor/